# How to write math symbols in plotly dash app?

Tags: python, latex, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to plot math symbols in a  plotly dash app.

For example, I've Tried this:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.P(r'$ Area (m^{2}) $'),
        dcc.Markdown(r'$ Area (m^{2}) $')
    ]
)
app.run_server()
```

and this was the result:

[image: result]

How can I get these result?

[image]

Comment: Did you read [this](https://chrisvoncsefalvay.com/2020/07/25/dash-latex/)?

Comment: About your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQzVR.png : Never write whole words like `Area` in math mode - this completely messes up the kerning

Comment: @rpanai your link is broken

Answer (score 3):

MathJax 3 works in Dash v2.3.0 which includes Plotly.js v2.10.0 with Markdown. Example: dcc.Markdown('$$y=x+1$$', mathjax=True)

Answer (score 2):

You can try Mathjax. The following works at my end (Python 3.9.1, dash==1.19.0, dash-html-components==1.1.2)

First create a javascript file (anyname.js) in the assets folder of your current project. In that file have just the following line:

```
setInterval("MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub])",1000);
```

Then back to your python file:

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_html_components as html

MATHJAX_CDN = '''
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/
MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'''

external_scripts = [
                    {'type': 'text/javascript',
                     'id': 'MathJax-script',
                     'src': MATHJAX_CDN,
                     },
                    ]


app = Dash(__name__, external_scripts=external_scripts)
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.P('''\(Area\)(\(m^2\)) '''),
    ]
)
app.run_server()
```

Some caveats:

- I have never been able to get Mathjax to work in the Markdown
  component.
- This solution doesn't work with the latest Mathjax version (nor with
  2.7.7). I am unsure which is the latest version it will work with.

If you are able to address any of the two caveats do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

With plotly you have to use unicode. For example if you want to print a greek letter mu is "\u03bc". You can obtain some symbols from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode) and superscripts from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts_(Unicode_block)). m square will be "m\U+2072".

Comment: This actually worked, upvote! Not only for plotly but in straight html.Div also. Example:
html.H1("beta is \u03b2")
The unicodes from the links didn't work for me though, but google "Unicode Character 'GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA" or letter of choice and remove the plus-sign and use only lower-case letters and you're there! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Install

```sh
pip install dash -U
```

Code

```py
import dash
from dash import dcc, html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Markdown('$Area (m^{2})$', mathjax=True),
])
app.run_server()
```

[image]