# LaTeX in dash not functioning

Tags: plotly-dash

I am using latex without any issue in jupyter notebook, now I am using jupyter dash and it is not working. any solution? Thanks

```
fig.update_xaxes(type='category',tickangle=-90,
                     title_text=r'$\gamma$',title_font = {"size": 20},tickfont=dict(size=18),row=1,col=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```py
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=r'$\gamma$'
)

fig.update_xaxes(
    type='category',
    tickangle=-90,
    title_font = {"size": 20},
    tickfont=dict(size=18),
    row=1,
    col=1
)
```

Here's plotly's [reference](https://plotly.com/python/LaTeX/) on using Latex for Dash

Comment: Hi Daniel, it doesn't work unfortunately. any other solution? Thanks

Comment: From that link: "Figure titles, axis labels and annotations all accept LaTeX directives for rendering mathematical formulas and notation, when the entire label is surrounded by dollar signs $...$. This rendering is handled by the MathJax library (version 2.7.5), which must be loaded in the environment where figures are being rendered. MathJax is included by default in Jupyter-like environments, but when embedding Plotly figures in other contexts it may be required to ensure that MathJax is separately loaded, for example via a <script> tag pointing to a content-delivery network (CDN)."

Comment: Here's a way to load Mathjax into dash, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379586/how-to-write-math-symbols-in-plotly-dash-app